# c++ empty constructor and member initialization

Tags: c++

I have confusion regarding default and empty constructor. Does empty constructor also initializes class variable automatically ? Meaning if i use a empty constructor instead of default constructor , does that also initialize class member variable automatically ? For example, if use following code, does integer pointer is initialized to NULL ?  Please confirm

**// .h file**

```
Class Test {    
public:  
   Test();
  ~Test();

   int *p;
}
```

**// .cpp file**

```
Test::Test()
{
   // do something..
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't initialize member variables automatically,

Comment: Some member types are initialized if not explicitly done so in the constructor's initializer list. Some are not. Pointers are not. It's the same as creating a variable in a function via `Type name;`.

Comment: Neither this nor a default constructor initializes `p` to NULL.

Comment: can you please elaborate then what is difference between default and empty constructor ?

Comment: If you don't create a constructor, the compiler creates one itself, which is the **default constructor**. But if you explicitly create the default constructor, it is still called **default constructor** but you may also call it **empty constructor**.

Comment: If you mean not providing any constructors vs. doing `Test(){}`, the only one I know of is that your class is now non-trivially-constructible, which loses it a couple of benefits. Any other slight differences should be along the same lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, empty constructor is same as default constructor if you don't initialize any member variable inside it.